Add a list of not shipped items to shipment email
In the "New Shipment" email templates, I am trying to add additional content to display the items that did not get shipped, such as in the case of a surprise out-of-stock item.
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Sales/layout/sales_email_order_pending_shipment_items.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items" name="pending.items" template="Magento_Sales::email/shipment/pending_items.phtml"/>
</body>

app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/shipment/pending_items.phtml
<?php
/** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items */
?>
<?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_order) : ?>
<?php $_items = $_order->getAllVisibleItems(); ?>
<?php
foreach ($_items as $item) {
    if ($item->getQtyOrdered() > $item->getQtyShipped()) {
        $pendingItems[] = [
            'name' => $item->getName(),
            'sku' => $item->getSku(),
            'qty_remaining' => $item->getQtyOrdered() - $item->getQtyShipped(),
        ];
    }
}
?>
<?php if (!empty($pendingItems)): ?>
    <h2>Items Yet to be Shipped</h2>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($pendingItems as $item): ?>
            <li><?php echo $item['name']; ?> (<?php echo $item['sku']; ?>) - Remaining Qty: <?php echo $item['qty_remaining']; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

I have added my new layout handle to the email template in Magento.

When I get my test email, after shipping only one of the items in my order, the items that did not ship do not display.

What am I missing to get this to work?

It looks like I had the "order" value wrong in the layout code in the email template in Magento wrong.
I had:
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_pending_shipment_items" order=$order}}

Updated to:
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_pending_shipment_items" order_id=$order_id}}

